# Cannot remove a symlink recursive

Tags: unix, symbolic-link, rm

During a delete of a backup, somehow the `rm -rf` got stock and couldn't delete a symlink.

Now, my folder looks like that:

```sh
$ ls
armips-master # folder
$ cd armips-master
$ ls
armips
$ readlink ./armips
armips/build/armips
```

I think I wrongly linked `example` to a folder in another directory called the same and now it refers to itself.

I want to delete this symlink but it's kind of recursive.
I tried:

- `rm -f armips`: `rm: armips: Invalid argument`
- `unlink armips`: `unlink: armips: Invalid argument`
- `cd ..; rm -rf armips-master`: `rm: armips-master/armips: Invalid argument`

Of course I don't want to go to `/dev/disk3s1` and I HARDLY REMOVE THAT FOLDER.
Even the Finder cannot delete that.

Comment: Rename the symlink: mv armips delme

Comment: `mv: rename armips to delme: Invalid argument` :(

Comment: but somehow it renamed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the symlink

```sh
mv armips delme
```

It shows an error: `mv: rename armips to delme: Invalid argument` but it works.
Next remove it:

```sh
rm delme
```